# Is there a way to search in only properties file when using grep?

Tags: grep, search

I am normally searching like this

> grep -rnws '/path/to/directory/' -e 'JMSAppender'

However this does display all jar files and class files where it might be used. I need to check only inside log4j properties in each projects.

Is there anyway to grep only properties files inside certain directories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you’re using GNU `grep`, you can specify globs to match against with `--include`:

```
grep -rnws --include '*.properties' '/path/to/directory/' -e 'JMSAppender'
```

The pattern must be quoted to ensure the shell doesn’t try to process it.